# The default target Entity Framework version requires the edmx schema version 2.0.0.0 or lower. The specified schema is version 3.0.0.0

Tags: entity-framework, edmgen

I'm pre-generating views in Entity Framework 5.0 with the EdmGen.exe as it follows:

```
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\EdmGen.exe" 
/nologo 
/mode:ViewGeneration 
/inssdl:"$(TargetDir)Base.ssdl" 
/incsdl:"$(TargetDir)Base.csdl" 
/inmsl:"$(TargetDir)Base.msl" 
/outviews:"$(ProjectDir)BaseViews.cs" 
/language:CSharp
```

The warning detail:

> Warning   3   The default target Entity Framework version requires the
>   edmx schema version 2.0.0.0 or lower. The specified schema is version
>   3.0.0.0. To avoid this warning specify the target Entity Framework version explicitly. You can do this by using the EdmGen.exe
>   command-line tool with the targetVersion option, or by including the
>   targetEntityFrameworkVersion parameter when calling the GenerateCode
>   method.

Any idea of how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `/targetversion:4.5` to EdmGen